# Reverse proxy to two different servers mapped to URL paths using NGINX

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, digital-ocean, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have searched Google and StackOverflow as well but not able to find exactly what I need. I also tried for 3 days but somehow it's not working.

I have 3 droplets on DigitalOcean. Each is accessible to each other through private IPs.

App1 is hosted on 10.139.207.6:3000
App2 is hosted on 10.139.207.8:80

This is my nginx config:

```
upstream app1 {
    server 10.139.207.6:3000;
}
upstream app2 {
    server 10.139.207.8;
}

server {
    server_name test.xyz.com;
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app1/;
    }
    location /app2/ {
        proxy_pass http://app2/;
    }

}
```

When accessing the `test.xyz.com` I get invalid host error.

Can you please tell me the right way to do this?

EDIT

I changed my nginx config to this and it's working now, but there is a strange problem:

```
server {

  server_name test.xyz.com;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://10.139.207.6:3000/;
  }
  location /blogs {
      proxy_pass http://10.139.207.8/$args;
  }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/proxy.koolkanya.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/proxy.koolkanya.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = proxy.koolkanya.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name proxy.koolkanya.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Now, I can open wordpress (app2) and a reactjs npm  (app1) but, app2 links are not working (as these are permalinks of wordpress).

Comment: Are you able to access http://10.139.207.8/app1 and  http://10.139.207.6:3000/app2 ?

Comment: `invalid host error` - are you able to resolve `test.xyz.com` from the command line using `host` or `ping` ?

Comment: @Andrea no, but I can access 10.139.207.8 and 10.139.207.6:3000 (without the /app1 and /app2). But again, that issue is solved, please see the updated question. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Oliver yes, the ping works, I have a different problem now.

Comment: @KumarRavi put the /blog location before the / location